# How to add a custom cell to a dynamicly generated tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Nearly during a week i'm trying to figure out how i can append a static-/custom tableviewcell to a dynamically generated tableview. I'm populating the cells based on the data i'm getting from the database. Basically what i'm trying to accomplish is like the following picture from the app ClassDojo: 
[image]

As you may know and see, you can add add as many groups as you want with the ClassDojo app, but the latest cell, in this case *Voeg een nieuwe klas toe*, will always stay at the bottom of the tableview. That's exactly what i'm trying to do.

What i tried to do till this moment is trying to calculate the latest cell in the tableview and trying to append my custom cell, but unfortunately i couldn't get my head around it.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if you guys need any code.

**---------EDITED POST---------**

I did accomplish to assign my custom cell thanks to @Slayter, but now i'm facing with the problem that my custom cell is immediately overwritten by my dynamically created cells (with Alamofire).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassDojo iOS Engineer here! More than happy to share how we do this.

Like [Slayter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141625/slayter) mentioned, we do

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count + 1 // Add one for your custom cell
}
```

But in addition we also do the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = nil;

    if self.indexIsForCustomCell(indexPath) {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CustomCell.reuseIdentifier)
        // Additional configuration
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(RegularCell.reuseIdentifier)
        // Additional configuration
    }

    return cell
}
```

Where CustomCell looks something like this (not exact):

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "CustomCell"

    // More code
}
```

And regular cell looks like:

```
class RegularCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "RegularCell"

    // More code
}
```

The reason your dynamic cells are getting overwritten is because of the line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Notice that you are using the same `cellIdentifier` regardless of whether or not it is the custom cell or the regular cells. This means that most likely you are doing the following:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(RegularCell.class, forIdentifier: "new group")
self.tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.class, forIdentifier: "new group")
```

When you should be doing:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(RegularCell.class, forIdentifier: RegularCell.reuseIdentifier)
self.tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.class, forIdentifier: CustomCell.reuseIdentifier)
```

OR

```
self.tableView.registerClass(RegularCell.class, forIdentifier: "regularCellReuseIdentifier")
self.tableView.registerClass(CustomCell.class, forIdentifier: "customCellReuseIdentifier")
```

By using the same identifier key, you are telling the `UITableView` to treat both cells as the same type. So when it needs to reclaim memory for a new cell being drawn on screen, it's going to use `RegularCell` and `CustomCell` interchangeably.

Hope this helped and thanks for checking out our App!

================= **EDIT** =================

Realized that I forgot to add the `indexIsForCustomCell` method. Here it is:

```
func indexIsForCustomCell(indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    if self.myData.count > 0 {
        return indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == (self.myData.count+1)
    }

    return indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0
}
```

Comment: Sir, thank you very much by stopping by my question. I will try your solution ASAP when i get the chanc, because now i'm on school. I'll let you now the result. By the way; i implemented an other solution to my app. Namely, i created a custom nib file as a UITableViewCell. Than i registered the nib file and used it as a footer for the section. May i know your opinion about this approach? Because if it's not efficient i will roll it back to my main approach by adding it within the `cellForRowAtIndex` function. Once again, thank you very much for your time and support. Really appreciated.

Comment: @OsmanSafaKaya your approach will work, but UITableViewCell gives you a bunch of additional code that you don't really need in a `tableFooterView`. For example, UITableViewCell contains everything inside of a `contentView` in additional to its base `UIView`. This isn't a huge deal but it is an additional set of data loaded and used. You could just use a UIView instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. While i'm trying to implement your solution to my project, i'm getting an error when i try to assign the `cell` to `nil`. You can see the error [here](https://i.imgsafe.org/7b54b0b.png). Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: my previous comment is fixed, but as you can see in my [code](https://i.imgsafe.org/457f9ed.png) i'm having trouble to get my code working as you have told me to do. The array groupNames has only 3 String values, but the else statement (_on line 201_ [see image](https://i.imgsafe.org/457f9ed.png)) runs it 4 times which will cause the following error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. How can i fix this?

Comment: @OsmanSafaKaya You're running into a classic fence-post error problem.

Remember that in iOS, arrays start at index 0 and end at count-1. So if you have 3 elements in an array, the valid indexes are: 0, 1, and 2. HOWEVER, `count` will give you the value in regular numbers, so count for `groupNames` returns 3. Line 201 shows you doing `count + 1` which returns 4. You should just be doing `(indexPath.row == self.groupNames.count);`

Comment: That did fix it indeed. But i'm getting a really weird fatal error now. I uploaded images that describes the steps i do to make the error occur: [image1](https://i.imgsafe.org/a61c527.png) -> [image2](https://i.imgsafe.org/a4d91e7.png) -> [image3](https://i.imgsafe.org/a4366bc.png). As you can see the indexes are correct; _0,1,2_ and it prints the right groupNames to the console. But when it comes to setting the groupNames to the `maincell.groupNameLabel.text` its crashing because it's out of range.. If it may help i uploaded a [gif](http://imgur.com/8FyNb3E).

Comment: @OsmanSafaKaya your image3 shows that the `groupNameLabel` is nil. You need to make sure to allocate the label before setting a value

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. You just need to tell the tableView to expect one more cell than what is in your data source.

**Example**

In your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, you will have something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count + 1 // Add one for your custom cell
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you just need to add some custom logic for that `indexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.row < myData.count {
        // configure cell as normal
    } else {
        // Add your custom cell logic here
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man!It helped a lot. Now I'm trying to reassign the cell variable to my custom cell inside the else statement like this: `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newgroup") as! newGroupCell` but it gives the following error: **Cannot reassign value of type 'newGroupCell to type 'mainGroupCell'.** (mainGroupCell is the cell i'm using for the dynamic cells). Do you know how i can tackle this?

Comment: I believe you need to register the class of your custom cell in your view controller. On mobile right now but in your `viewDidLoad` method you need to put something like: `self.tableView.registerClass(newGroupCell.class, forIdentifier: "new group")` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! I will experiment with that and come back later if i find some other solution.

Comment: @OsmanSafaKaya after rereading your comment, you'll need to declare the cell in the if statement and else statement. You can't reassign a value to a different type after declaring it. You'll probably also need to do the registering I talked about earlier I think.

Comment: That was indeed what i did. But then my custom cell is overwritten by the dynamic cells. As i wrote above in my edited post. Do you have any clue why that happens?